# Distribution of 2 lists randomly to another 2 lists

Tags: python, list, random, distribution, converters

I have two lists A and B
,

and P1,P2

and I need to take A,B and randomly distribute them to lists P1,P2

```
A = [ A1,A2,A3,A4 = "A1","A2","A3","A4" ]

B = [n101,n102,n103,n104 = "101","102","103","104"]
```

This loop should distribute the lists 4 times randomly until all P1 and P2 get filled up randomly

```
for i in range(4):
    if(i <= 3) and a == 3:
        P1 = range(A1,A2,A3,A4,n101,n102,n103,n104)
        a += 1
    
    if(i <= 3) and b == 3:
        P2 = range(A1,A2,A3,A4,n101,n102,n103,n104) 
        b += 1
```

expected result

```
P1 = A4,101,104,A2
P2 = 102,A3,103,A1
```

P1,P2 random distribution from A,B

Comment: What is your question?  Can you share some actual, `meaningful` input/output? Eg. what's `A1...`?

Comment: `random.sample(A + B, len(A) + len(B))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_sample.asp) method in the [random](https://www.w3schools.com/python/module_random.asp) module for this. Since you don't want duplication in the second list, you can use a for loop to exclude all the values available in both `P1` and `A+B` and create a new list. Then you can use sample to again get a list with random values.

```
import random

A = ["A1","A2","A3","A4"]
B = ["101","102","103","104"]

P1 = random.sample(A + B, 4)

new_list = []

for x in A+B:
    if x not in P1:
        new_list.append(x)
        
P2 = random.sample(new_list, 4)

print(P1)
print(P2)
```

Output:

```
['104', '102', 'A4', '103']
['101', 'A2', 'A1', 'A3']
```

Use `len(A)` as the 2nd argument in sample() method, if the length of your list is not always 4.

Comment: You can make it significantly more efficient if you will just shuffle combined list of `A` and `B` *(`buf = random.sample(A + B, len(A) + len(B))`)* and split it by length of `A` after *(`P1, P2 = buf[:len(A)], buf[len(A):]`)*.